# Combining two indepedent normal distributions - without summing

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations, normal-distribution

I am trying to understand the probability of a sports event given two normal distributions of variables that contribute. I don't think summing the means in this case is correct but happy to be proven otherwise.

For example, if we look at 'corners' in football (soccer) for a particular team - We have the distribition of the HomeTeam being awarded corners (mean = 4, sd = 2), and we have the distribution of the AwayTeam conceding corners (mean = 5, sd = 2.5).

Can somebody explain to me how I can combine these normal distributions into one, so that I can then understand the probabilities of x corners for the Hometeam?

As corners awarded = corners conceded in anyone game, I don't think summing the means and variance is the correct procedure.

I'm not sure if I'm over complicating this and need to just take average, but if someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

(Apologies for bad formatting - this is my first foray onto the Maths Exchange!)

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @herb: two teams one of which has a distribution (not normal, but no matter) for corners awarded to it against other teams and the other has a distribution for corners conceded to other teams.  The question is about how to combine these to get a probability distribution for a match when these two teams meet.  There is no right answer

Comment: " probability distribution for a match".  What is the random variable?  match?  Random variable should be some sort of number.

Comment: The random variable for the "home" team is the number of corners awarded to it during a match. For the "away" team, it's the number of corners awarded to its opponent during a match.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn’t clear - Ionza is correct. The variable is the amount of corners. Both the home and away team have their own stats.